# Best place to find Android Button

Tags: png, photo

Can anybody tell me ,  where can I get PNG button?

Comment: I'd imagine Google.

Comment: Have you searched somewhere? please mention it and see how to ask a question

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is to design it yourself. Design it with Adobe Photoshop and then parse it to html or XML. There is a very good tool in Photoshop to do that. You can use this video as a guide

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BM59afMRDU